# Unable to locate package camera_calibration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I do

> rosdep install camera_calibration

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query

> Missing resource camera_calibration
>
> ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
>
> ROS path 1]=/home/tintin/catkin_ws/src
>
> ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share

A similar question was posted [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/62673/camera_calibration-package-not-detected-and-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-sensor_msgs/) but there isn't a complete solution yet. I tried the solution given there too.

1. For

> sudo apt-get install camera_calibration

I am getting "Unable to locate package camera_calibration"

2. For

> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-image-pipeline

I am getting "Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-image-pipeline"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270767/unable-to-locate-package-camera_calibration/) by [Sulphur](https://answers.ros.org/users/31675/sulphur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the errors that you posted it looks like you're using Kinetic. I'm not sure about the error that you're getting with `rosdep`, but the reason that you can't install `image_pipeline` (which  contains the `camera_calibration` package) is because you're trying to install the version for Fuerte. Try

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-pipeline
```

You can install many packages using the following command format

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distribution>-<package-name>
```

where `<distribution>` is the distribution that you're using and `<package-name>` is the package that you're trying to install.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bansi_lol](https://answers.ros.org/users/55945/bansi_lol/) on 2020-06-26**:
I tried the same command sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-pipelline but with my distribution name which is ros melodic but it have the same error cannot find package what could be the problem then?

**Comment by [bansi_lol](https://answers.ros.org/users/55945/bansi_lol/) on 2020-06-26**:
Sorry my mistake I copied and pasted the command and didnt notice there is a spelling mistake **pipeline

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-06-26**:
Thanks for catching the mistake. I've updated the answer.